# SEO and single page website in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo, singlepage

I am developing single page website in Wordpress nad I run into a problem. I will try to explain it as best as I can.

The website is http://wpweby.cz/sbeauty/

Currently, when you hover menu item Kosmetika, you can see there is link **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/#kosmetika** - that is how visitor is redirected to the section Kosmetika on the page. But this is bad for SEO, I need URL to be **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika** so it is indexed by Google. That is my first problem.

Now, second problem for me is that when I create page in Wordpress administration, it automatically creates URL for that page - so for example for Kosmetika, there exists URL **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika**. Although no visitor will get to that page through my website, it exists therefore Google will index it - and that's why anyone can get to that page through Google. Yes I can disable indexing of **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika** in robots.txt, but that doesn't solve my problem - I want URL **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika** to be indexed, but on the homepage for section with id kosmetika.

So basically, I need this:

1, Actual page **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika** to be removed (or Wordpress not to create URL for pages)

2, Every section on front-page to have its own indexable URL, so **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/#kosmetika** to be **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika** and I need this to be indexed by google

I searched a lot and unfortunately I haven't found anyone dealing with this specific problem. I'd be glad if you could help me somehow. Thank you very much!

And sorry for links not being active in my post, I don't have enough reputation here to post more than 2 links..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i would say is that you cant change the links with **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/#kosmetika** to **wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika** as it is a single page site and you can only navigate to sections using anchor tags

The other alternative to have your page indexed and work fine is to redirect the ***wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika*** to ***wpweby.cz/sbeauty/#kosmetika*** using a plugin in wordpress

refer to these links to get a better idea about indexing in google and redirecting a url to other

[Indexing anchor tags in single page site](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/anchor-links.html)

[Redirecting to a specific url in wordpress](https://managewp.com/the-best-way-to-set-up-redirects-in-your-wordpress-blog)

Hope this would give at least an idea to think better on your problem

Comment: Now, are you sure about me not to be able change links? I have found a website - http://www.medio.cz and their structure is exactly what I need (the difference is I need it in Wordpress). If you take a look at their menu links, they are directing to www.media.cz/reference for example and if you click it you are still on the same page but it scrolls down to chosen section.

I also found great tutorial - http://www.iprospect.com/en/gb/blog/parallax-scrolling-and-seo-how-to-use-jquery-to-seo-your-website/

Comment: but I think I can't apply that on Wordpress site, since wordpress site creates URL for every page created in Wordpress administration.

The alternative with redirecting you mentioned - it would be good, but Google would penalize my site because of duplicated content (content of wpweby.cz/sbeauty/kosmetika is the same as content of wpweby.cz/sbeauty/#kosmetika). And also it isn't very user friendly for visitor to by immediately redirected after visiting certain page from Google.

Anyway, Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @Kosta789 Thank you i will check it out & get back soon